# Jpa Entity conditional relationship mapping?

Tags: java, jpa, uml, entity-relationship

I have Person Class and Zone Class.

If Person Type is RESPONSABLE a One To One BiDirectional should be applied.

If Person Type is GARD A MANY TO ONE should be applied.

is there a way to achieve this ????

For Starter I want to provide this but @Where annotation seems unrecognized:

```
    @Entity

public class Personnel implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private int Age;
    private Date dateDeRecretement;
    private String Login;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypePoste poste;

    @Where(clause = "poste = 'GARDE_NUIT'")
    @ManyToOne
    private Zone zone;


    @Where(clause = "poste = 'GARDE_JOUR'")
    @ManyToOne
    private Zone zone1;


    @Where(clause = "poste = 'RESPONSABLE'")
    @ManyToOne
    private Zone zone2;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Personnel() {
        super();
    }   
    public int getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }   
    public String getNom() {
        return this.nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }   
    public String getPrenom() {
        return this.prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }   
    public int getAge() {
        return this.Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int Age) {
        this.Age = Age;
    }   
    public Date getDateDeRecretement() {
        return this.dateDeRecretement;
    }

    public void setDateDeRecretement(Date dateDeRecretement) {
        this.dateDeRecretement = dateDeRecretement;
    }   
    public String getLogin() {
        return this.Login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String Login) {
        this.Login = Login;
    }   
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }   
    public TypePoste getPoste() {
        return this.poste;
    }

    public void setPoste(TypePoste poste) {
        this.poste = poste;
    }
    public Zone getZone() {
        return zone;
    }
    public void setZone(Zone zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }
    public Zone getZone1() {
        return zone1;
    }
    public void setZone1(Zone zone1) {
        this.zone1 = zone1;
    }
    public Zone getZone2() {
        return zone2;
    }
    public void setZone2(Zone zone2) {
        this.zone2 = zone2;
    }

}
```

This is the UML Diagram to represent what I am trying to achieve.

[image: UML Diagram To Achieve]

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a simple constraint like

[image]

This constraint could be written as a nice OCL for sure. But a) I'm not that firm with OCL and b) a coder should be able to implement it correctly this way.